# SessionSecurityToken - The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, adfs, ws-federation

I am attaching an exact print of the error.

The application is hosted in IIS and uses ADFS authentication. A single person managed to reproduce this error out of like 10 people. It reproduced every time even after restarting the browser, deleting cache & cookies on her machine. It stopped reproducing after restarting the app pool or a machine restart on her side. I am betting on the IIS app pool restart, since I already tried with restarting the browser and deleting the cookies and it didn't solve anything.

The only "custom" behavior we are doing is sliding the token in this way in the SessionSecurityTokenReceived event  :

```
           var token = e.SessionToken;
             e.ReissueCookie = true;
            e.SessionToken =
                new SessionSecurityToken(
                    token.ClaimsPrincipal,
                    token.Context,
                    DateTime.UtcNow, //Start date
                    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)) //Expiration date
                {
                    IsPersistent = token.IsPersistent,
                };
```

IsPersistent is logged and it's always evaluated to false. Would this be the problem? I don't think so. From some google searches I see that people usually set it to true when doing token sliding.

One other search said to try creating the token this way :

```
           var sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
            e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                                 token.ClaimsPrincipal,
                                 token.Context,
                                 DateTime.UtcNow, //Start date
                                 DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),//Expiration date
                                 true);
```

Is there any difference in creating the token by using "new SessionSecurityToken.." vs "sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule; sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken" ?

I am available for any other details.

Thank you

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyKr.png)

Comment: We have the same issue, have you figured anything out yet?

Comment: I did 2 changes. I used "sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken" and refreshed the validity of the token only when in it's second half of validity period

Comment: May i know how did you do it, second half of validity period?